# jQuery .getJSON() URL Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, getjson

This is the JSON data that is retrieved when I use the `(METHOD REDACTED)` method:

```
[{
    "group_option": {
        "OptionsID": "28",
        "MenuGroupID": "6",
        "group_options_name": "Select two (2) sides :",
        "menu_group_option_information": null,
        "menu_group_option_min_selected": "0",
        "menu_group_option_max_selected": "2",
        "fDateAdded": "2014-01-25 08:29:20",

        "group_option_items": [{
            "item": {
                "OptionItemID": "69",
                "menu_item_option_name": "Mexican rice",
                "menu_item_option_additional_cost": null
            }
        }, {
            "item": {
                "OptionItemID": "70",
                "menu_item_option_name": "Refried beans",
                "menu_item_option_additional_cost": null
            }
        }, {
            "item": {
                "OptionItemID": "71",
                "menu_item_option_name": "Poblano rice",
                "menu_item_option_additional_cost": null
            }
        }, {
            "item": {
                "OptionItemID": "72",
                "menu_item_option_name": "Charro beans",
                "menu_item_option_additional_cost": null
            }
        }, {
            "item": {
                "OptionItemID": "73",
                "menu_item_option_name": "Caesar salad",
                "menu_item_option_additional_cost": null
            }
        }, {
            "item": {
                "OptionItemID": "74",
                "menu_item_option_name": "Southwestern mashed potatoes",
                "menu_item_option_additional_cost": null
            }
        }, {
            "item": {
                "OptionItemID": "75",
                "menu_item_option_name": "Roasted corn succotash",
                "menu_item_option_additional_cost": null
            }
        }, {
            "item": {
                "OptionItemID": "76",
                "menu_item_option_name": "Poblano cheese corn grits",
                "menu_item_option_additional_cost": null
            }
        }, {
            "item": {
                "OptionItemID": "77",
                "menu_item_option_name": "French Fries",
                "menu_item_option_additional_cost": null
            }
        }, {
            "item": {
                "OptionItemID": "78",
                "menu_item_option_name": "Fiesta salad",
                "menu_item_option_additional_cost": null
            }
        }]
    }
}]
```

Here is my other relevant code:

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="../JQUERY/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
    <script>
        function getOptions() {
            var html = new String();

            $.getJSON('<URL HERE>', function (data) {
                alert("function");
                //var data = JSON.parse(data);
                var h = new String();
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    h += '<div class="data">';

                    h += data[i]['group_option'].OptionsID + '<br>';
                    h += data[i]['group_option'].MenuGroupID + '<br>';
                    h += data[i]['group_option'].group_options_name + '<br>';
                    h += data[i]['group_option'].menu_group_option_information + '<br>';
                    h += data[i]['group_option'].menu_group_option_min_selected + '<br>';
                    h += data[i]['group_option'].menu_group_option_max_selected + '<br>';
                    h += data[i]['group_option'].fDateAdded + '<br><br><br>';

                    for (var iter = 0; iter < data[i]['group_option']['group_option_items'].length; iter++) {

                        h += data[i]['group_option']['group_option_items'][iter]['item'].OptionItemID + '<br>';
                        h += data[i]['group_option']['group_option_items'][iter]['item'].menu_item_option_name + '<br>';
                        h += data[i]['group_option']['group_option_items'][iter]['item'].menu_item_option_additional_cost + '<br>';
                        h += '<br><br><br>';
                    }
                    h += '</div>';
                }
                alert("h");
                alert(h);
                html = h;
                alert("html equals ");
                alert(html);

            });
            alert("returning html");
            alert(html);
            return html;
        }
    </script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var str = "";
            str = getOptions();
            $('#content').append(str);
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="content"></div>
</body>
```

I've used `.ajax` and I've gotten nothing and now I'm trying to use `.getJSON`. I still haven't been able to retrieve the data from the website. It seems to never want to get past `.getJSON(url, function(data)`

My Questions

1.Why won't my code let me get into my `.getJSON` function?

2.What do I need to change to access my data in my `.getJSON` function?

Comment: check for errors in console, you might want to use console.log() instead of alert() as well

Comment: im not getting any errors

Comment: Check whether path to jquery library is proper

Comment: You got any alert to be alerted?

Comment: yes right after my .getJSON function call

Answer (score 0):

add the fail function to getJson method and see if you get any errors there

```
$.getJSON("", function(){
    ....
})
.fail(function( jqxhr, textStatus, error ) {
    var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
    console.log( "Request Failed: " + err );
})
```